# Can a CSS overflow scrollbar be controlled in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a `div` with a class `overflow: auto;`  Is there a way to control this scrollbar when it appears?

I have a ajax photo gallery (no page refresh) where some caption text is in a `div`, but the content is of varying length.  If you scroll down in this div and then advance to the next slide, the scrollbar does not go back to the top.  So, I was wondering if there was a way to control this scrollbar.  Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With jQuery, you can set the top of the scroll area like so:

```
$('#contents').scrollTop(0);
```

[Here's a demo showing this in action->](http://jsfiddle.net/Ender/Rc8dq/)

Note that this is also possible without jQuery:

```
document.getElementById('contents').scrollTop = 0;
```

[And a demo of that->](http://jsfiddle.net/Ender/WBzD7/)

For both demos, press the Reset button to set the scroll bar back to the top.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Let me investigate this as well.

Comment: I'm awarding the answer to Ender.

Answer (score 4):

You can change the value of the property `scrollTop` of the `<div>` element.

See [element.scrollTop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.scrollTop) on MDC docs

See [element.scrollTop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534618%28VS.85%29.aspx) on MSDN

While `scrollTop` is not part of any standard, it is supported by all major browsers.

Comment: Interesting.  Thanks. Let me investigate this.

Answer (score 4):

To move the vertical bar back to the top on an overflowed element `myControl` , you must do

```
$("#myControl").scrollTop(0);
```

or, in case of horizontal bar, to move it to the beginning (left)

```
$("#myControl").scrollLeft(0);
```

If you want to hide the scroll bars, you must do this CSS

```
#myControl {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

You are assuming that the next slide resides on the top. If you have absolute positionated slides, you might better do the following, to ensure that you scroll to the correct nextSlide location:

```
var nextSlidePos = $("#slide" + nextSlide).position();
$("#myControl").scrollTop( nextSlidePos.top ).scrollLeft( nextSlidePos.left );
```

Answer (score 1):

Update after a test, using `elm.scrollTop = 0`:

```
<div style="overflow:auto;height:100px;width:100px">
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>
    <a href="javascript:" onclick="this.parentNode.scrollTop = 0">go up</a>
</div>
```

Comment: This is not the browser's scrollbar. This is the scrollbar that appears on the div, because it has a overflow: auto CSS declaration.  The content is appearing inside the div.

Comment: I've never used it but did you try `div.scrollTo(x, y)` ?